# SWIFT decodable data transfer

Tags: arrays, json, swift, parsing

I have a **usernameTextField** in the viewController where I enter a username and a button **searchTapped** with the following code:

```
@IBAction func searchTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        guard let username = usernameTextField.text, username != "" else {
            displayWarningLabel(withText: "Information is incorrect")
            return
        }

        guard let gitUrl = URL(string: "https://api.github.com/users/\(username)/gists") else { return }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: gitUrl) { (data, response, error) in

            guard let data = data else { return }
            guard error == nil else { return }
            do {
                let gitData = try JSONDecoder().decode([Gists].self, from: data)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.gists = gitData
                }
            } catch let error {
                print(error)
            }
            }.resume()

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "GistsSegue", sender: nil)
    }
```

after I get the data from json I want to save the data into an array **gists** outside of this method, but this does not happen.

```
 var gists = [Gists]()
```

What could be the problem?

Just in case, this is my model for parsing json:

```
struct Gists: Codable {
    var description: String?
    var files: [String: DetailGist]
}

struct DetailGist: Codable {
    var filename: String?
    var raw_url: String?
}
```

Comment: show the JSON response

Comment: What do you have in mind? What `gitData` is not an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self.gists = gitData` is being called but it is called long after you call `performSegue`. This is the nature of asynchronous data access.

Simply move your `performSegue` call to be just after you set `self.gists`.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.gists = gitData
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "GistsSegue", sender: nil)
}
```

Comment: I moved the method `performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)`, but it did not help ... the data in the array `self.gists = gitData` is still not preserved

Comment: Is that line even called? Use the debugger and see what is happening. Perhaps one of your `guard` statements is returning.

Comment: I understood what the problem is.
My segue did not directly access the second viewcontroller but through the UINavigationController. I fixed the method `prepare(for segue:` and everything worked `override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        
        if let dvc = segue.destination as? UINavigationController {
            if let targetController = dvc.topViewController as? GistsViewController {
                targetController.username = self.username
                targetController.gists1 = gists
            }
        }
    }`